# select and count based on a condition

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, `proj: id name` and `proj_reports: id, position, created_at, key_id, proj_id` and
I want to select from `key_reports` for each `proj_id`:

```
- total number of `key_id` which can be done with `count(.key_id)`
- total number of DISTINCT `key_id` `count(DISTINCT .key_id)`
- total number of `key_id` where `position` > 1
- total number of `key_id` where `position` > 2 AND < 5
```

The problem that I have is that I don't know how to add those conditions for checking if the position is > or < a number or in a range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a CASE expression inside the COUNT aggregate funciton.

```
SELECT
    COUNT( CASE WHEN position > 1 THEN key_id ELSE NULL END ) AS GT1,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN position > 2 AND position < 5 THEN key_id ELSE NULL END ) AS GT2LT5,
FROM
     proj_reports
```

The COUNT aggregate does not count NULL values, so that's why it works.

[Here is a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3371d/3) that demonstrates the concept.

Comment: how can I count the position for distinct key_id, `COUNT( CASE WHEN position > 1 THEN key_id ELSE NULL END ) AS GT1` where key_id DISTINCT? Thank you for your time:)

Comment: COUNT( DISTINCT CASE ... )

Comment: I tried that, but is not giving the right result, edit: because I need to count the distinct key_id with only one position, because a key_id can have multiple positions.

Comment: Can you post your table or a table that represents an example of the data?